# Magento 2 Best Seller Product Collection in Deleted order also

Tags: magento2, sales-order, product-collection

**`index.php`**

```
protected $_coreRegistry = null;
    protected $_collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
       \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }



    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
    public function getBestSellerData()
    {
        $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()->setModel(
            'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product'
        );
        $collection->setPageSize(100);

        return $collection;
    }
```

**`phtml`**

```
<?php $bestSellingCollection =  $block->getBestSellerData();
echo $bestSellingCollection->count();
foreach ($bestSellingCollection as $value) {

    print_r($value->getData());
    # code...
}?>
```

it shows count **`55 products`** I deleted all order in my Database. bUT sTILL SHOWING 55 WHAT IS THE PROBLEM

**`Also recently I Place one Product that it not showing in this collection I placed one prodect it's not showing`**

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this strange results because the bestsellers reports does not read data from the products or sales tables directly.
It reads the data from `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily` or `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly` or `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`, depending on the period you chose.

Comment: What basis it works when ever i change it always show some data. Is it My collection is correct